# Return all results of substring with in string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have some odd data in a vendor database but need to be able to extract multiple different parameters from one field in the db.

So from this example i would like to pull out all items that fall between ("  %  ")

Between quotes is a string, disregard that it looks like code:

"Func_GetParameterLatestValue("IBW Patient Height RT Assess") kHeight =Func_GetParameterLatestValue("Height For IBW Vent Misc")  If (kSex) = "" Then
Return_Value =NULL  Else If kHeight > 0 Then        If kSex=1 Then                   Return_Value= Round(((kHeight - 152.4)*.91)+50,0)          Else
Return_Value= Round(((kHeight - 152.4)*.91)+45.5,0)      End IF     Else                          Return_Value = NULL     End IF  End IF  ' Return_Value = kHeight '("IBW Patient Height RT Assess")"

so the return values would be:

```
IBW Patient Height RT Assess,
Height For IBW Vent Misc,
IBW Patient Height RT Assess
```

Im open to any suggestions to try and make this work.  Ideally i would like to be able to slam the results in a subquery as well to make sure that they exist on another table.

This query currently returns the first instance

```
select vbs.Name, 
        SUBSTRING(sd.FormulaDetails, 
                  CHARINDEX('("', sd.FormulaDetails)+2,(CHARINDEX('")',sd.FormulaDetails) - CHARINDEX('("', sd.FormulaDetails))-2)
from StatementDefinitions sd, MvVBScript vbs
where sd.ScriptID = vbs.ID
```

Comment: You need to clarify this question. Are you asking how to substring the column results for some query? The above code doesnt even look like T-SQL.

Comment: sorry, it wasnt mean to look like code, its an actual piece of string text only....

Comment: I'm more of a .NET guy than a SQL guy... so I'd lean towards a CLR-UDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this recursively with a WITH statement. Here's a shot at it. Change varchar(max) to whatever the data type of your FormulaDetails column is. In case you want it, this query returns the ScriptID and numbers the position of the chunk it finds (so 'Height For IBW Vent Misc' would be occurrence 2)

```
with Chunks(id,occurrence,position,token,remainder) as (
  select
    ScriptID,
    cast(0 as int),
    charindex(@token,FormulaDetails),
    cast('' as varchar(max)),
    substring(c,charindex(@token,FormulaDetails)+1,len(FormulaDetails))
  from StatementDefinitions
  where FormulaDetails like '%'+@token+'%'
  union all
  select
    id,
    occurrence+1,
    charindex(@token,remainder)+position,
    cast(substring(remainder,1,charindex(@token,remainder)-1) as varchar(max)),
    substring(remainder,charindex(@token,remainder)+1,len(remainder))
  from Chunks
  where remainder like '%'+@token+'%'
)
  select id, occurrence, token from Chunks
  where occurrence > 0
  order by id;
```

Comment: hey steve, thanks for this.  What is 'C' in the first substring?

Comment: Oops. c should be FormulaDetails, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: thats what i thought but im getting zero results back :(

Comment: Hi cjparker, Here's a SQL Fiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4817d/2 I fixed one mistake, but not one that would have prevented you from getting results. Hopefully this will help you use this idea.

Comment: i totally must have mis entered something, seems to work pretty good after i used the query from sqlfiddle.  thanks Steve!